# How to increase page speed for my website

Tags: jquery, css, .net

how to optimize the website?How to increase page speed. i have done minified javascript and Css. Also done images optimzation.but still google is penalizing us for pages.

Comment: What is your effort?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad for StackOverflow, but you might consider using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to get an idea of what you can improve.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can increase the page speed of your website, They include -

- Minify CSS
- Minify JS
- Minify HTML
- Compress images
- Defer loading Javascripts
- Use browser caching
- Compressing using `gzip`

Comment: how to implement browser caching for mvc?

Comment: You should google that